# How do I get my JSP's online?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I feel dumb for asking this question because after searching for three hours I kept getting answers that were over my head. I am reminded that I am still very new to web programming.

I have written up a cool little application that with jsp's, a mysql database and have been hosting it locally (on the localhost) to test it and whatnot. Well, now I want to put it online. Is tomcat only for localhosting? Or is there just some funny ip address url that I could type in from another computer to gain access over the internet? Or do I have to do something special like package all my files into something special and drop them into a some third party software.

I found a little bit about port forwarding and right now if I can enter url `http://localhost/priorq/queue.jsp` and see my page. So I think I got the port forwarding thing figured out..

Comment: Do you just want to access your application from another computer on your local LAN or do you want to have anyone on the Internet access your application?

Comment: I want it publish it for the world to use. So yeah, internet access.

Comment: Do you want to expose your local computer to the Internet and publish your application that way or do you want to find a company that can host your application for you?

Comment: I want to expose my computer for now. If it ever gets too slow I will get a third party to host it (I am currently looking into the google app engine for java).

Answer (score 2):

1) Your must have a fast internet connection if you're planning to have a high usage by visitors and don't want to get your site permanently inhibited.
 Pay attention to an upload speed. It's very important.

2) If you plan to develop your site for commercical purposes then you need get static local IP address from your provider. In order to users can find your site on an easy to remember URL.

3) And of course, your computer must be turned on all the time to have round the clock access to your site.

4) You need install a web server. [Apache Server](http://httpd.apache.org) is excellent suitable for this mission.

5) You should open or redirect necessary ports (usually it's 80) to be able to access your site on the network.

6) And also you need to configure or disable a firewall to allow traffic through on port to reach your web server software.

Here are 2 good references on this topic:

[Host my web site on home computer](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/hosting/host_web_site_home_computer.php3)

[Advantages and shortcomings of home hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28504/can-i-make-my-home-computer-a-server/28506#28506)

Answer (score 0):

To expose your local JSP application to the Internet will most likely require firewall changes on the network device (router) that provides your computer with Internet access.  Here is a web page that generically talks about setting up [port forwarding](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router) on a router.

BEWARE!!  Exposing your internal computer to HTTP port 80 traffic can make your computer vulnerable to getting HACKED!  Your MySQL database is also at risk to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) depending on how your application has been written.  This is especially more likely if you are new to programming and are not fully aware of the best practices for securing a web site and for writing secure code.

Here's a link to an [IBM document on securing a Web server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-secureweb/).